# how to create a popup uipicker and uitextfield for iOS 7?

Tags: ios, popup, uitextfield, uipickerview, uipickerviewcontroller

I need to add pickers to my textboxes, but can't figure out how to get them to work.  I've gone through a number of tutorials that show you how to start from scratch, which is kinda useless if you have an existing app and you're wanting to add functionality, for the most part they're not very helpful.

I'm looking for something very similar to the image below.  The one displayed below is obviously a **UIDatepicker**, but ideally

> I'm looking for a custom picker for "place", "term", and "gate".

So for now, skip the UIDatepicker item, and **focus on the custom picker item.**

> One more thing, this is iOS7, and I am using **storyboards** AND **arc**!

[image: popup pickerview]

I ran across this (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtmQp5aP304) which was really helpful, but again it's starting from scratch.  What I can't figure out is how to implement this within my existing code.  So I'm looking for a walk-through, a tutorial that someone can point me at to get me started.

> There is this on stackoverflow ->
>   [how to pop up datePicker when text filed click and disappear when editing done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587087/how-to-pop-up-datepicker-when-text-filed-click-and-disappear-when-editing-done)

Which gave me a few ideas, but not exactly what I'm looking for, tried the suggestions and ended up with more errors than anything else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
 @interface ViewController ()<UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

@implementation ViewController
{
  UIPopoverController *popoverController;
      NSString *currentPick;
    ….
}
.
.
.
-(void)makePicker{

 UIPickerView *picker = [[[UIPickerView alloc]init]autorelease];
        picker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 1000);
        picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        picker.delegate = self;
 UIButton *done = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [done setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Save.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [done setFrame:CGRectMake(260, 10, 50, 30)];
        [done addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 UIButton *cancel = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [cancel setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cancel setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 30)];
        [cancel addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


 if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        UIActionSheet *pickerAction = [[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:[cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:Nil otherButtonTitles:nil]autorelease];
                    [pickerAction addSubview:picker];
        [pickerAction addSubview:done];
        [pickerAction addSubview:cancel];
        [pickerAction showInView:self.view];
        pickerAction.frame = CGRectMake(0,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 330,320, 350);
    }else
    {
        UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];
        [popoverView addSubview:picker];
        [popoverView addSubview:done];
        [popoverView addSubview:cancel];
        [popoverContent.view addSubview:popoverView];
        popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
        [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:<your frame> inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
        popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 260);
        [popoverView release];
        [popoverContent release];

    }
}
.
.
.

// mainArray here is a NSArray of several arrays, these arrays contain the titles for different selections… e.g. @[fontArray,colourArray,nameArray]

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [[mainArray objectAtIndex:clickedAt] count];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 return [[mainArray objectAtIndex:clickedAt] objectAtIndex:row];
}
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   currentPick = [[mainArray objectAtIndex:clickedAt] objectAtIndex:row];
}


- (void)doneButton:(UIButton *)button
{
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    UIActionSheet *as = (UIActionSheet *)[button superview];
    [as dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
else
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

// save your selections here using currentPick object
}

- (void)cancelButton:(UIButton *)button
{
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    UIActionSheet *as = (UIActionSheet *)[button superview];
    [as dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
else
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Enjoy  your Picker ;)

Comment: thanks for the response.  I know where to add the delegate view (in the .h file), but "implement number of components" ?  what components ?

Comment: -(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView

Comment: numberOfComponentsInPickerView & numberOfRowsInComponent  .. the two required functions for pickerView delegates

Comment: great.  newb question, where should those go ?  since we're doing this programmatically, I'm a little lost here.  Could you do me one more kind courtesy and go back to the code you posted and add notations of what goes where in my viewcontroller.m and .h files ?  remember -> NEWBIE...ok ?  Thanks.

Comment: edited my code for better understanding, ….and i have a reputation of "1" sir, you're not NEWBIE :D

Comment: wow, that's much clearer, thank you.  hmmm just one little tiny problem Im using ARC, and your code is throwing errors.  And while I may have a reputation of 47, and you just 1, trust me this stuff is gobblygook at this point... :-)

Comment: just remove every [<object> release], [<object> retain]  and [<object> autorelease] statements from my code :)

Comment: 2 errors -> 1.) "[cells objectAtIndex:" is producing 'use of unidentified cells' error.  2.) "<your frame>" ?  I'm guessing this is the name of the layout that we're referencing ?  That said, don't I need those release statements ?

Comment: spoke too soon.  the lines for mainArray is throwing errors as well.  I have to define that first, somewhere....

Comment: i've included a comment about mainarray ,,. just define your own constraints like you do for table views also..

Comment: I saw that.  I have to be honest, I don't know how to create constraints for table views.  So I'm guessing at this point that I have to create an array, call it mainArray.  But your statement makes me think otherwise, that I have to create array of arrays...and if that's case, I'll have do some more research.

Comment: that's because you have to give values for different cases, i found array of arrays to serve me better ,,u may come up with better.. for better understanding of those please go through the developer library section for picker view delegates .. or search for sample picker view delegates,, hope that helps

Comment: UIPopoverController doesn't work on iPhone, this solution will not work for @MagicMiles

Comment: @paul i know that, that's why i've added check for device(action sheet for iphone & popover for iPad)

Comment: @nickAtStack, with the help of a friend, I had to make a few modifications to your code in order to get it to run.  However, still no joy.

Comment: oh,, i wrote that code for my first ever app,, i'll give u an easier alternative on monday :)

Comment: Apple docs state not to add views to the ActionSheet, and I'm pretty sure on iOS 7.0 that causes issues. It's a hack, and it's not the best way to do it.

Comment: @Paul , i appreciate that but let me tell u sir, my application makes use of it pretty well and it's live on market without any kind of issue…..

Answer (score 1):

check this, make a full screen **UIView** , a **UIImageView** , a **UIPickerView** and two **UIButtons** (**save** and **cancel**)in .xib  then 
make their outlets in your .h file:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *bg_view;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *bg_customImageView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *myPicker;
- (IBAction)cancelOut:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)saveOut:(UIButton *)sender;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *saveButton;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *cancelButton;
```

then in .m file:

```
-(void)customPickerShow
{
[self.bg_view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.25 blue:0.05 alpha:0.5]];
[self.bg_view setHidden:NO];
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
[self showMyPicker];
}

-(void)showMyPicker
{
[self.myPicker reloadAllComponents];
[self animatePicker];
}

-(void)animatePicker
{
self.cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake((framewidth/2) - 130, frameheight, 70, 1);
self.saveButton.frame = CGRectMake((framewidth/2) + 60, frameheight, 70, 1);
self.bg_customImageView.frame = CGRectMake((framewidth/2) - 140, frameheight, 280, 1);
[UIView beginAnimations:Nil context:Nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
self.bg_customImageView.frame = CGRectMake((framewidth/2) - 150, frameheight - 230, 300, 300);
self.cancelButton.frame = CGRectMake((framewidth/2) - 130, frameheight - 220, 50, 50);
self.saveButton.frame = CGRectMake((framewidth/2) + 80, frameheight - 220, 50, 50);
[UIView commitAnimations];
}


- (IBAction)cancelOut:(UIButton *)sender {
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
[self.bg_view setHidden:YES];
}

- (IBAction)saveOut:(UIButton *)sender {

// save here your selections

self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
[self.bg_view setHidden:YES];
}
```

call this **[self customPickerShow];** function to make it work..

This will look like action sheet with picker and buttons.. you can customize with your choice of **background image** and your choice of **frame in animatePicker function**

**Don't forget to make this bg_view at top of other views and make it sethidden by default**

Comment: Hmmmm, Im using storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

Purely using UIStoryboard probably won't be able to either solve the project, or not the best way. This is my solution. 
1) Create a CustomPicker
2) Define your Datasource and Delegate
3) Attached the CustomPicker to the inputView of the target TextField.
4) you can set it up at the delegate method 
    -(Bool)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField

In this approach, we add the Picker by coding it (not by UIStoryboard).

I have [this demo project](https://github.com/loftyet/LJTableViewTextFields) to show this purpose.